# SVN history wont go past yesterday, while SVN Checkout works fine

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I try to run an SVN update, it wont update past yesterday's last revision.
Opening the log in Tortoise SVN won't let me select past yesterday either. All dates past yesterday are greyed out when I try to select the "To" date in the "From/To" boxes in the log viewer.

Doing a Checkout of the project in a new directory however, returns the actual latest revision (commited today). After that, the new directory has the same problem, and won't update past yesterday.

I've tried changing the system time to tommorrow, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. Also, my co-workers have absolutely no problem updating, commiting and viewing the log.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `TortoiseSVN Settings`;

You can try to restore the defaults values in `log caching`. I do not use `Cached repositories` but I suspect it could impact your results if you have configured this.

In `Dialogs1` the `Default number of log messages` could impact your display.

You can also try to clear histories in the `Save Data` menu : clear the logs, maybe the authentication data (make sure you know your credentials :D)

Comment: I just tried your suggestions but sadly don't see any change in behaviour :( Thanks for the effort though :D

Comment: Your suggestions seem to have worked after reboot, thanks a bunch :)

Comment: No pb, hope it won't reappear :P

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether your working copy is somehow mapped to a different branch or tag.
2. Try using the command-line client: run `svn update` from the command line and paste its output into the question above.

Answer (score 0):

When I saw this problem, it was because my checkout was only including /trunk, whereas the missing revision affected only files in the root, outside of /trunk.